# What are the equivalents of Rex and stats of Splunk in Datadog logs?

Tags: splunk, datadog

In splunk queries, I could use **rex** to create new fields and use **stats** command to group and get statistics on those fields. What are the equivalent of those in Datadog Logs? I see faucets in datadog logs but they don't seem to be customized like rex.

I tried researching for all datadog queries to get fields auto created and couldn't find any.